# matlab program to load .MAT files matlab workpace programmatically

Tags: matlab

I wrote a MATLAB code to load .MAT files

```
clc;
close;
val=load('C:\Users\Debian\user\cs640 machine learning\assignment5\MNIST.mat');
csvwrite('C:\Users\Debian\user\cs640 machine learning\assignment5\MNIST.csv',val);
```

however the file I get in return is empty file.
i.e. the file in C:\Users\Debian\user\cs640 machine learning\assignment5\MNIST.csv is a blank file the computer keeps rotating rotating for a long long time but then I get a blank file.
What is the error in above statements? 
The original file MNIST is a 30 Mb file.
I am trying to implement Bayes minimum risk classifier in MATLAB I have been asked not to used any library function.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The next time, provide a minimum working example and stick to the necessary infos (the file size and the Bayes may just irritate people). Matlab provides a quite neat IDE, use it for debugging (e.g. the workspace window). That may stress @mattesyo's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `load` function is a structure and `csvwrite` can't save structures.

Try:

```
val=load('C:\Users\Debian\user\cs640 machine learning\assignment5\MNIST.mat');
val=struct2cell(val);
csvwrite('C:\Users\Debian\user\cs640 machine learning\assignment5\MNIST.csv',val);
```